# Login as domain user fails in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, ssh, login, likewise-open

Using `pbis`, joined a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) node to the domain successfully.

```
# /opt/pbis/bin/get-status
LSA Server Status:

Compiled daemon version: 8.2.1.2979
Packaged product version: 8.2.2979.68390
Uptime:        0 days 20 hours 50 minutes 29 seconds

[Authentication provider: lsa-activedirectory-provider]

Status:        Online
```

It's also listing all the domain users as expected when we run `getent passwd`.

```
# getent passwd ttuser
ttuser:x:1124089581:1124073985:Test User:/home/<domain>/ttuser:/bin/bash
```

But when we try to login as domain user either through su or ssh it's failing with pam authentication failure.

**When tried to login from the same machine using su:**

```
su[7024]: pam_unix(su:auth): check pass; user unknown
su[7024]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=ubuntu uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=ubuntu rhost=
su[7024]: pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
su[7024]: FAILED su for <Domain>\ttuser by ubuntu
su[7024]: - /dev/pts/1 ubuntu:<Domain>\ttuser
```

**When tried to login from different machine using ssh:**

```
sshd[7031]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
sshd[7038]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
sshd[7038]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=ip-172-21-3-42.eu-west-1.compute.internal
sshd[7031]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for <Domain>\\ttuser from ip-172-21-3-42.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with either prefixing or not prefixing the domain to the user. Assuming your password is correct.

Comment: I tried both domain as prefix and without. I have also have enabled the config `AssumeDefaultDomain`. And yes, password is right.

Comment: I don't see enough info to help further. It would just be guess this and guess that.

Comment: @ETL Please let me know what additional info that you would require to help me debug this issue.

Comment: Full config of likewise-open, event logs on the domain controller for the login attempt, etc